# Is there any way of making xdotool type more reliable inside a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, xdotool

I use some shortcuts where I call a list of useful commands with `zenity` and then I can make it type long commands I wouldn't memorize by heard on the terminal... When I'm using Ubuntu as the main operating system `xdotool type 'my commands'` never fails... However, if I use another Ubuntu in a virtual machine with the full screen, even though I can call the shortcuts of my main operating system, xdotool misses some letters on long commands.

I wouldn't like having to configure shortcuts directly inside the virtual machine just because of that. Is there any workaround for that? Is there any way of making xdotool more reliable inside a virtual machine? Considering it's being used from the outside system?

Comment: You may use the clipboard instead, using a tool such as `xclip` to store a snippet in the clipboard. Then you can have `xdotool` issue the keyboard combination to paste the clipboard. This is much more reliable than `type`, where indeed, depending, characters may be lost. Alternatively, you may increase the delay in typing, but it will quickly start to become slow.

Comment: @vanadium I actually use some of my snippets that are pasted with `xclip` already. However, the way I'm creating those snippets they will always have a new line at the end. And that's a problem on the terminal because a new line means pasting and executing the command... However, perhaps using `sed` to take out this last new line and using `xclip` is really the way to go here... I haven't considered that while making this question...

Comment: I am using `head -c -1` to strip the last line, i.e., a CR,  which always seems to be added to text files:  `head -c -1 "$SNIPPYDIR"/"${SELECTION}" | xsel -bi`

Comment: @vanadium As per comment below my deleted answer, OP states problem is his VM doesn't parse `<` and `>` keys properly. This should probably be put into the title and explained in the body of the question.

Comment: I cannot test that, unfortunately.